# Double Press on Back Button not working

Tags: android

I have a problem on my double press on back button, I have an activity where I can add my data into the database. And my problem is every time I add something then goes to the main activity,  when I do the double press on back button it will be redirected to the add activity.

Here's my onBackPressed code in main activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
 if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce == true){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Press once again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

can anyone help on how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
private long lastPressedTime;
private static final int PERIOD = 2000;// 2 sec

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (event.getDownTime() - lastPressedTime < PERIOD) {
                // todo your 
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Press once again to exit",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                lastPressedTime = event.getEventTime();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Where should I put the exit line? In the *todo your* space? @AKSiddique

Comment: @HunterWinchester Remove your onBackPressed and used this piece of code.

Comment: That's what I did. Still the same

Comment: Please clear your view what do you want to do with your database.

Comment: What does the double-press-to-exit function have to do with my database? @AKSiddique

Comment: @HunterWinchester I don't get your point what do you want to do with your database in onbackpressesd.

Comment: Nothing with my database. I just want my app to exit on back pressed.

Comment: @HunterWinchester exit your app either single click or double?